# Why does memcpy() handle integer destination as Big Endian but does not for char destination?

Tags: c, endianness

The computer I am running the following code is Little Endian.

```
uint32_t src_uint = 0xAABBCCDD;
uint32_t dest_uint = 0;
uint8_t dest_arr[4] = {0};

memcpy(&dest_uint, &src_uint, 4);
printf("\ndest_uint: 0x%X\n", dest_uint);
// output: 0xAABBCCDD

memcpy(dest_arr, &src_uint, 4);
printf("\ndest_arr : 0x");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%X", dest_arr[i]);
// output: 0xDDCCBBAA
```

For me, the second output (0xDDCCBBAA) is correct because my computer is little endian. However, the first output (0xAABBCCDD) should be instead 0xDDCCBBAA since Little Endian would store variable `src_uint` in memory as: 0xDDCCBBAA. It seems that either memcpy() is not being transparent regarding its arguments or C compiler handles int differently in those situations...

Thank you!

Comment: Type cast `&dest_uint` to `uint8_t *` and print it one byte as a time.

Comment: I see nothing related to big endian here

Comment: 0xAABBCCDD is 0xAABBCCDD big or little endian the int will display 0xAABBCCDD.

Comment: the second will be or at least can be 0xDDCCBBAA on some systems but you have to check the processor docs before making such an assumption.  big endian does not conform to a single global standard.  nor would little for that matter.  99% of the time when endian is mentioned it has been used/assumed improperly.

Comment: `memcpy` copies sequential *bytes* regardless of what they happen to represent. It has no notion of endianness, nor is there anything in the posted question that would suggest otherwise.

Comment: No, dest_uint is stored little-endian as well.  So when the processor reads it you get the original value.  Only type punning can reveal the implementation detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about `memcpy()` but rather how you access the destination. In the first case, you're accessing the value as a `uint32_t`. In the 2nd case, you're accessing the memory one byte a time.

On big endian systems, those will give you same result. On little endian systems the results are reversed.

[image: Endianness (from wikipedia)]

Answer (score 4):

> For me, the second output (0xDDCCBBAA) is correct because my computer is little endian.

Or to put it another, more specific way, that output proves that your C implementation does indeed use little-endian representation for type `uint32_t`.

> However, the first output (0xAABBCCDD) should be instead 0xDDCCBBAA since Little Endian would store variable src_uint in memory as: 0xDDCCBBAA.

That conclusion does not follow from the antecedent.  Yes, the value of `src_uint` is represented in memory as the byte sequence 0xDD 0xCC 0xBB 0xAA.  And there is every reason to think that `memcpy` faithfully copies that byte sequence to the representation of `dest_uint`.  When your program interprets that representation as a value of type `uint32_t`, the resulting value is expressed, by and to hexadecimal-reading humans, as 0xAABBCCDD.

If you print the value of `src_uint` too then you will get the same result.

Do not be confused between the numeric values represented by objects of numeric type and the in-memory representations of those values.  C programs can and do expose the latter, as you demonstrate, but most operations are defined in terms of the former.